# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'destination')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-context

[image: Problem 1]
[image: Problem 2]

When I manually go to the **localhost:3000/hotels** route it gives me these errors. I know error is coming due to not getting value, so how can it be solved? It would be great if you could help by looking at the github code.

Comment: Hey @Md please share your full code here or on https://codesandbox.io/ to solve your query.

Comment: It seems better if I give the GitHub link?

Comment: You have to share your full code here or codesandbox.io

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Tonmoy01/hotel-booking/draft/romantic-tesla

Comment: When you've the chance, please edit this post to include the relevant code you are working with instead of images of code. Images are not accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Route state only exists from the transition from one route/path to another route/path. If you directly navigate to a specific page the state just simply won't exist. For this I suggest applying some defensive coding techniques: use null checks on the `location.state` object and provide a fallback value (*if necessary*).

Example:

```
const { state } = useLocation();

const [destination, setDestination] = useState(state?.destination ?? "");
const [dates, setDates] = useState(state?.dates ?? {});
const [options, setOptions] = useState(state?.options ?? []);
```

Note that since we've no idea what these states represent or their types I just picked the fallbacks at random, obviously you'd provide valid fallbacks that suit your code's needs.

Comment: thank you so much! but, there is another problem. dates[0] is error. can I share the code?

Comment: @Md.TonmoyKhan If the `dates` state is supposed to be an array, then your code should probably handle empty arrays gracefully. For example `const [dates, setDates] = useState(state?.dates ?? []);` and later `dates?.[0] ?? {}`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startDate')

Comment: <span onClick={() => setOpenDate(!openDate)}>{`${format(
                dates[0].startDate,
                'MM/dd/yyyy'
              )} to ${format(dates[0].endDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}`}</span>

Comment: @Md.TonmoyKhan Like I said, the frontend code should handle null/undefined data gracefully. Here you could do something like `{dates[0].startDate && dates[0].endDate && <span onClick={() => setOpenDate(!openDate)}>{format(dates[0].startDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')} to {format(dates[0].endDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}</span>}` where the `span` is conditionally rendered only when there are dates to display a range for.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Tonmoy01/hotel-booking/draft/romantic-tesla?file=%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fpages%2Flist%2FList.jsx

Comment: Please, check my code...

Comment: @Md.TonmoyKhan Sorry, what are you wanting me to check in your code?

Comment: Yes... Probably I can't tell you the full problem, it's best if you check my code.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you have not passed a "destination" property. So if you go back to your initial page and you add a destination, the /hotels url would now work. To make the page work regardless you have to use:

const [destination, setDestination] = useState(location.state && location.state.destination ? location.state.destination: "");

this checks if there is a location.state object exists (can be checked using console.log(location), and if it does exists we check if the destination property is also true, if both conditions are true then we set destination to location.state.destination, if the property is null (no destination has been inputted) then it returns an empty string: "".

This can also be done for .date and .options